# ABAQUS: Defining varying material properties in a single part using a point-map of values

Tags: abaqus, finite-element-analysis

I'm working on a project involving FEM modeling of fractured femurs to assess the performance of fracture fixation devices.  Bone is a highly complex material, with bulk elastic properties that vary depending primarily on the local density of the bone.  The particular problem in my research is the development of a patient specific model by converting data from CT scans to a map of the material properties in the bone.  This is a common procedure, but with most software, it renders it impossible to alter the actual geometry of the bone, which I will need to do in order to study the fracture behaviour.

Generating the geometry of the bone from CT scan is quite simple.  So is pre-processing the scan images in slices and using voxel intensities to determine bone density and thus elastic behaviour, stored as a pointcloud (i.e. x-y-z spatial data paired with material property, defined in a grid/array according to scan slices).  The problem that I am having is mapping these properties onto the geometry/mesh in a way that will allow me to edit the geometry of the bone (i.e. introduce a fracture, screws, and locking plate).  Is there a way of defining the variation in the material properties in a way that will also allow me to edit the bone geometry?

I have tried to define the material properties as "temperature dependant" and then use temperature as a surrogate field by which to apply the point-cloud map of properties.  This approach has apparently been used successfully before in research, but details of the implementation weren't given.  In small scale tests this is successful, but it does not work on the scale at which I need.  ABAQUS seems to give up after the number of points in the point-cloud exceeds 10,000.  Using 4mm voxel size, this requires at least 20,000 points defined across the volume of bone.

I have also considered using the UTEMP subroutine, but don't know the Fortran coding to implement this.  If this would be a workable solution to my problem, I will happily learn and use this approach.

Comment: The problem is that each element is assumed to be homogenous - all of the same material.  An element can be isotropic or anisotropic.  Your mesh would have to be constructed so the elements follow the density gradient.  I'm not sure I understand what "give up" means.  Limits on element and node counts would depend on the RAM available on your machine.

Comment: @duffymo Each element is considered homogeneous, but if a material is defined as temperature dependant, the elastic modulus is determined at each integration point based on the temperature values at the element nodes.  The interpolation of nodal temperatures from a pointcloud is independent of element orientation.  My problem is that the built in point-cloud field definition only allows 10,000 points to be defined-- this is too few to get an accurate mapping of bone density as described in my question.  The problem is not to do with the mesh, but with assigning nodal temps.

Comment: Yes, I understand that very well.  I have not used ABAQUS or its point-field cloud.  I wonder if it's possible to accomplish it in code using their UMAT subroutine.  You'd need to express the temperature as a function of (x, y, z), but the UMAT subroutine would be called for each integration point in the element without an extra memory requirement.  Your mesh resolution would still have to be very fine.

Comment: I had an 18-year period of my career applying FEA to non-linear problems in solid mechanics and heat transfer using MARC, a competitor to ABAQUS that also came out of Pedro Marcal's group at Brown University.  I'm familiar with the techniques, but not the details of the ABAQUS implementation.

Comment: Coming up with a function to fit the density distribution in 2D or 3D space could be challenging.  I'm not suggesting that it's easy, but it's an alternative approach that might solve your issue with the point cloud constraints.

Answer (score 0):

This answer will not fix your problem, but will hopefully point you in the right direction.

Generally, there are two methods for creating an FEA model for a bone:

**The first method** entails using a CT image (bigger pixels) and then calculating material properties (i.e. Young's modulus) from the pixel intensity. We can then create an element for each pixel and the elements will have different materials. This can be done using [BoneMat](https://ior-bic.github.io/software/bonemat/index.html) or its FOSS alternative [py_bonemat_abaqus](https://github.com/elisepegg/py_bonemat_abaqus). It allows for fewer elements but the model will be homogeneous.

**The second method** requires using a micro-CT image. At that scale, all of the details will be captured and you will have a homogeneous model with all of the intricacies of the cortical and cancellous bone reflected in the geometry. The good news is that all elements will have the same properties as the cortical bone, which is available in the literature. This method usually uses a voxel-based mesh, but You may be able to use software such as mimics. I have developed a free and open-source software named [VCAMS](https://vcams.mkhoshbin.com/) as part of my PhD thesis, but it will not be publicly available for a few weeks. You can send me an email from my website for more information.

The main problem for you will be incorporating screws and fixtures in the model. A voxel mesh may not be compatible with that due to imperfect contact, but you won't know unless you test it. Furthermore, these methods create an *orphan mesh*, which cannot be edited, only deleted via boolean operations.